# How to set custom date in ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using `ngx-bootstrap datepicker`. I want a custom date to be highlighted on load of `date-picker`. I have a date stored in some variable and want that date to be selected(highlighted).

component.ts

```
private dob : string = '2017/07/07';
```

component.html

```
<datepicker [activeDate]="dob" [showWeeks]="false" [startingDay]="1" [formControl]="form.controls[dob]"></datepicker>
```

But this is not working. By default today's date will be selected even after setting `activeDate`. How to achieve this? Or is there any other attribute that I can use instead of `activeDate`? And is there any particular format for date?

Comment: can you create a plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngModel` did the trick for me. Instead of setting the value to `activeDate` we can set it to `ngModel`. And also `activeDate` accepts a Date object, which will need a conversion if the value is a string.

I had to remove `formControl` as well, since it did not work along with `ngModel`.

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="dob" [showWeeks]="false" [startingDay]="1" (selectionDone)="showDatePicker = false"; ></datepicker>
```

Comment: Hi @amit can you please help me out on this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191162/angular-6-and-bootstrap-4-date-picker

Comment: how to set date for daterangepicker